# Как сделать внешние двумерные массивы видимыми внутри lamda выражения

Tags: c++, c++14

Внутри метода класса в цикле создаётся несколько lamda-выражений. Как мне обратиться к двумерному массиву который является private членом этого же класса внутри этого выражения (расширить область видимости)? Мне нужно сделать это не через указатели.

Ниже представлен участок кода который компилятор отказывается принять (member «ListenerBss::receive_circilar_buffers_” is not a variable).

```
#include <functional>
void ListenerBss::Initialize(const std::list<LinuxUart>& in_ports_of_base_stations)
{
    number_of_bss_ = in_ports_of_base_stations.size();
    int16_t i = 0;
    for (auto uart : in_ports_of_base_stations){
        ports_of_base_stations_[i] = uart;
        ReceiveDataFromUartFunctors[i] = [&i,receive_circular_buffers_,&front_receive_cursor_](char* data, const uint16_t& length) mutable -> void { // 
            int16_t port_number = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++){
                receive_circular_buffers_[front_receive_cursor_[port_number]][port_number] = data[j];
            }
        };
        uart.BindReceiveEvent(ReceiveDataFromUartFunctors[i]);
        i++;
    }
};
```

Comment: `[i,this](char* data, const uint16_t& length)  { .... }`, если хочешь обратиться к переменным - членам класса.

Comment: Chorkov большое спасибо.

Comment: @Chorkov, написали бы ответом. И Вам репутация, и вопрос закрыт.